# My stylesheet is linked but the style is not applied, how can i make it work?

Tags: css, node.js, express

I am trying to link a stylesheet to an app I am currently building using express and node.js. The problem is that the stylesheet is being linked to the webpage if I hit the inspect/sources I can see it is linked and the code inside it but it is not applied to my webpage.

The stylesheet is saved under public/stylesheets/app.css.

My code on the app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

// Mongoose Config

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    title:String,
    image:String,
    body:String,
    created:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);

// RESTFUL ROUTES
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/blogs")
});
app.get("/blogs", function(req,res){
    Blog.find({},function(err,blogs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.render("index.ejs", {blogs: blogs});
        }
    });
});
app.get("blogs/new", function(req,res){
    res.render("new.ejs");
});
    




app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server started!!!");
});
```

The one that is included in the header.ejs:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Blog App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css" integrity="sha512-+AdxWMqfOdtwMuXK482e5OgHYzN06s97n3NTAeAdTlUvlIgCBx3SUKvMculJIedylDfVCaQFdD6HaojI4aeBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script type="text/javascript" rel="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
            <div class="ui container">
                <div class="header item"><i class="paper plane outline icon"></i>Blog Site</div>
                <a href="/" class="item">Home</a>
                <a  class ="item" href="/blogs/new">New Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the code in the stylesheet

```
i.icon{
    font-size: 2em;
}

.container.main{
    margin-top: 7.0em;
}

body{
    background-color:red;
}
```

I am also using semantic UI for style

Comment: `href` should be `href="./stylesheets/app.css"`, I'm assuming the file structure here, so if you could post your file structure better answer could be given.

Comment: Can you add more of the HTML? We don't know what your markup looks like.

Comment: UPDATE: this is my whole header.ejs file

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console? For example, if it shows a 404 error, it means that the path in href is wrong. The other alternative would be that semantic.css overwrites your new styles, as you load it after your stylesheet.

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz no i do not get any error actually if I look at inspect/sources i can see that the stylesheet is there but if I look on the inspect/networks i can see it is not linked

Comment: You need a route (probably using `express.static()`) that will serve your stylesheet.  By default an Express server serves no files at all.  So, you need a route that will cover every file you want the web server to send back to the browser. You can use `express.static()` to serve an entire directory of static files.  And, your style sheet link should then be `/stylesheets/app.css` and you can point `express.static()` at the parent of the `stylesheets` directory.

Comment: @jfriend00 this is what i have basicly done the stylesheets parent directory is the public directory so using this app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

Comment: And, did you change to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">`?  And, did it work?  You can see in the Chrome inspector whether the browser's request for that stylesheet succeeded or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep did that and no change

Comment: Well, you have to look in the Chrome inspector to see if the specific browser request for the stylesheet succeeded or not?  And, if not, what the error is. This is elemental debugging which you need to learn to do for yourself since we can't do it remotely.  And, did you restart your server?  And, reload the page with Shift-F5 to bypass the cache?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the order of the links to the multiple stylesheets.

The original order was:

This means that the app stylesheet is read and applied first, and afterwards, the stylesheet for semantic-ui is applied.

If something has styles applied in both stylesheets, the latter will have precedence over the former (assuming selector specificity is the same, and no !important is applied.

You can read more about precedence here: https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED IT: it seems the problem was that i put the link to the stylesheet before the link to the UI-semantic idk why that would be a problem but at least it solved it.

BTW if anyone knows why this interaction happens pls leave an explication

Answer (score -1):

It seems your path is wrong for the css file